# Find the index of the largest item in List<string> smaller than a given string value

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list of strings.

Given a string, I must find the index in the list of the largest string that is smaller than the given string.

For integers I know how to do it:

```
   int givenInteger = 10;
   List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
   int index = myList.IndexOf(myList.Where(x => x < givenInteger).Max()); // 8
   int result = myList[index]; // 9
```

My question is how to implement this for a list of strings.

```
string givenString = "10";
List<string> myListOfStrings = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" };
int index = myListOfStrings.IndexOf(myListOfStrings.Where(x => x < givenString).Max()); // Error    28  Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'

string resultingString = myListOfStrings[index];
```

Comment: HINT: Try converting the string to int

Comment: Do you have int in the form of string type in your list? what is expected output if the `myListOfStrings = {"Hello", "10", World};`

Comment: @hallie I tried using Int32.Parse(x) andInt32.Parse(givenString) in the index expression before I posted this question, but I got error messages.

Comment: If you tried something you thought should work and it didn't then you need to tell us that in the question. Show us EXACTLY what you tried and tell us EXACTLY what happened.

Comment: @ Prasad Telkikar All the strings in the list myListOfStrings  are integers in the form of string. In your example though, I would expect the order to be: 1. "10", 2. "Hello" and 3. "World", so the expected index value would be -1, because "10" is the smallest string. If instead of the given string "10" it would be: "Large", I would expect the result "Hello" (index 0) as "Hello" is smaller than "Large".

Comment: @ Prasad Telkikar All the strings in the list myListOfStrings  are integers in the form of string. In your example though, I would expect the order to be: 1. "10", 2. "Hello" and 3. "World", so the expected index value would be -1, because "10" is the smallest string. If in stead of the given string "10" it would be: "Large", I would expect the result "Hello" (index 0) as "Hello" is smaller than "Large".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you would like to do this:

```cs
x < givenString
```

you would actually do this:

```cs
x.CompareTo(givenString) < 0
```

`x.CompareTo(y)` will return less than zero if `x` is less than `y`, zero if `x` is equal to `y` and greater than zero if `x` is greater than `y`. It will actually return -1, 0 or 1 but you should not rely on `CompareTo` returning any specific value other than zero. Any non-zero value is valid when the values are not equal and it is just the sign that indicates the relative order.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to compare the numerics values you need to convert the value to int with the int.Parse methood.

Now you can compare by the values but if you want to compare the strings values use the CompareTo() function.

```
string givenString = "10";
List<string> myListOfStrings = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" };
int index = myListOfStrings.IndexOf(myListOfStrings.Where(x => int.Parse(x) < int.Parse(givenString)).Max()); 


string resultingString = myListOfStrings[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's parse `givenString` into  *integer value* (`int`, `long`, `BigInteger`):

```
int givenInt = int.Parse(givenString);
```

then we can loop over `myList`:

```
int index = -1;

for (int i = 0, max = 0; i < myList.Count; ++i)
  if (int.TryParse(myList[i], out int value) && 
      value < givenInteger && 
      (index < 0 || value > max)) {
    max = int.Parse(myList[i]);
    index = i;
  }

string maxString = index < 0 ? null : myList[index];
```